# Query to get result like Country vs Country using SQL/Hive

Tags: sql, join, hive, cross-join

Folks,

Recently i faced a question where i cant get the actual answer. Please give me suggestion to get expected result.

**InputDataset**

```
Table Name : Country_List

Country
Ind
Aus
China
Us
Eng
NL
Pak
SRL
```

I Need to get possible combination of above mentioned dataset like country1 vs country2

**Expected Result**

```
Ind Vs Pak
Ind Vs Aus
China VS ind
China Vs US
SRL VS Ind
```

similarly i need to get all possible combination without duplicate.

Note : Ind VS Pak and Pak Vs Ind both are same.we need only one out it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below logic

```
WITH CTE
AS(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Country) RN
    FROM Country_List
)


SELECT DISTINCT A.Country, B.Country 
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN CTE B ON A.RN < B.RN
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a `cross join` or `join` with inequality:

```
select cl1.country, cl2.country
from Country_List cl1 cross join
     Country_List cl2
where cl1.country < cl2.country;
```